# Take each line of any input txt into a separate variable

Tags: bash, shell

I want to make a script that will read a multi line input and put each line into a separate variable.

I will not know how many lines the input will have or what each line will contain.

If someone could help me fill in this in I would appreciate it

while read -r line

```
do
   #somehow make each line of $line a separate variable

done #after hitting enter? not sure how to do that
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
i=0
while read line
do 
  array[$((++i))]=$line
  echo ${array[$i]}
done < file
```